# CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization not showing alert second time

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

Calling [CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] doesnt show the alert after the user selected "Dont Allow" option for the first time. Is there anyway to force the app to show the alert again when needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple won't display your alert if the user has already pressed `Don't Allow`.
On the other hand, you can check the authorization status and show a pop telling the user to go to settings and changing it manually.

```
CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    // Show request
}
```

Regards